# Setting up nginx to proxy (adding SSL) SMTP with authentication

Tags: nginx, smtp, proxy

In my organization we are migrating a certain web+mail setup, and I think that maybe nginx can be suited to do what I want, but I cannot fully understand the [official documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/mail/ngx_mail_core_module.html).

I have a certain web application (in-house) at machine A, with a set of users. The machine A is capable to send mails as *@example.net.

I want to allow some users to send mails as certain_group@example.net, but not as user@example.net (certain users share some groups, and a user has several allowed groups). Can I set the nginx to authenticate the user against a certain URL, and allow or disallow a certain user depending on the MAIL FROM field?

If I can receive a request [just like one of the last examples](http://nginx.org/en/docs/mail/ngx_mail_core_module.html) (same link):

```
GET /auth HTTP/1.0
Host: localhost
Auth-Method: none
Auth-User:
Auth-Pass:
Auth-Protocol: smtp
Auth-Login-Attempt: 1
Client-IP: 192.0.2.42
Client-Host: client.example.org
Auth-SMTP-Helo: client.example.org
Auth-SMTP-From: MAIL FROM: <>
Auth-SMTP-To: RCPT TO: <postmaster@mail.example.com>
```

I could take good decisions from the web application... provided that this works when authentication is not none. But when authentication is something ( LOGIN or PLAIN), I don't know if the `Auth-SMTP-From` will be sent to `auth_http`.

Am I on the right track? Can it be done? Is there another way? A better way?